# Does stationarity have to be satisfied for a time series regression problem?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am recently trying to build a time-series regression model to predict for the output flow rate of a reactor given some upstream conditions.  The reactor behaves quite cyclically because the operators make two different products, each at a 10 hour interval. One product results in a low flow rate due to it being more viscous. I am predicting the flow rate as a function of 5 different inputs (such as temperature, pressure) upstream.

I understand that stationarity is a big deal when dealing with AR, MA or ARIMA models.  But such models are 1D, and does not look at additional regressors.  For regression problems, do stationarity also have to be satisifed?

Furthermore, if stationarity is desired, should I just difference the flow rate (i.e., difference = Q(t) - Q(t - 1))?

Comment: stationarity requirements are all about the error process. The original series can have trends or level shifts or monthly factors but the residuals from a useful model need to be free of structure. In terms of whether or not you need to difference .. let the data speak as to the ultimate form UNLESS you have a prior specification which is often useful. As you said arima is 1d while the inclusion of causals gets you to a Transfer Function or SARMAX